# How can I protect a page in confluence from accidental changes?

Tags: confluence

I use custome template in confluence with Task list elements to create a page
[image]
Description of content using checkboxes - is very important for me

After creating any page the user can click on an item by chance and thereby change the value of the field

How can I protect a page from accidental changes ?
I don't want to use Page Restrictions, maybe there is another solving of this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The only method I found for achieving this was to write JavaScript inside a `{html}` macro which gets the current userid, checks the userid against a list of allowed users, if the userid is not on the list then disables or hides the HTML code on the page in this DOM so the current user can't change it. This is not the best way or recommended but it can work quite well.

For example, to hide the checkbox from users who are not logged in:

```
{html}
<script>
AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
   if(jQuery(".login-link").size()>0) { 
      AJS.$(".checkboxeditclass").hide();
   }
});
<script>
{html}
```